# What is the difference of nth powers of the roots of quadratic equation

Tags: roots, quadratics

Suppose I have a quadratic equation of the form $x^2-2bx-c=0$ with roots

$k_1=b+\sqrt{b^2+c}$ , and

$k_2=b-\sqrt{b^2+c}$

Is there a general formula for

$t_n=(k_1)^n-(k_2)^n$?

I wanted to calculate this because I wanted to know, given $t_n$ and $t_{n+1}$ can we calculate $(b,c)$?

Edit: changed mistake in formula for $k_1,k_2$

Comment: As to the question, not sure what you are hoping for.  Given, say, $(x-1)(x-3)$, you are looking for a formula for $3^n-1$?  There is, of course, a good recursion satisfied by the $t_n$.

Comment: @lulu thanks, mistake on my part, edited the formula..

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a generalized function in terms of b and c for t(n).

Comment: $t_{n+2}=2bt_{n+1}+ct_n$ implies $u_{n+2}=2bu_{n+1}+cu_n$ where $t_n=u_n\sqrt{b^2+c}$.

Comment: To answer the last question, you can find $b$ and $c$ from the recurrence above, but you need four consecutive $t_n$.